# PHP - How can I load the same form with some differences concerning the type of fields?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form with some fields of type text and 2 fields (`name` and `second name`) that have a value by default, and these 2 fields are of type="hidden".

Now, I would like to add a link on the form "Fill an order for another person". If the user click on this link the same form must be reloaded but with a little difference: the fields name and second name must be of type text to allow the user enter a name/second name.

I can reload the form, but the fields `name` and `second name` remain hidden, because I don't know how define a condition that say to change the types if the user clicks on the link.  Could you explain how can I do this?

The fields that are filled by default:

```
if ($field_label=="Name")
{
    return sprintf("<div class='ginput_container'>$name<input name='input_%d' id='$field_id' type='hidden' value='$name' class='ginput_container' $max_length $tabindex $html5_attributes %s/></div>", $id, $field_id, $html_input_type, esc_attr($value), esc_attr($class), $disabled_text);
}
else if ($field_label=="Second name")
{
    return sprintf("<div class='ginput_container'>$secondname<input name='input_%d' id='$field_id' type='hidden' value='$secondname' class='ginput_container' $max_length $tabindex $html5_attributes %s/></div>", $id, $field_id, $html_input_type, esc_attr($value), esc_attr($class), $disabled_text);
}
```

Comment: `type="text"` ? sorry i can't get the question

Answer (score 1):

add another input field and call it something like "form_submitted". set the value of this to 1.
you will be able to check for this in your php script once you've submitted the form. if this value is set use text if not use hidden

EDIT: If you want to only display one additional form you can create it on page load and use javascript to make it visible once a user clicks on the link 
if you want to be able to add multiple forms, use javascript to build the new ones. each click on the link can add another form. the only thing you need to make sure is that you update the name of the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reload the form. You can just use jQuery to remove the existing hidden field, and create a new textbox in it's place, with the same value as the hidden one.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/FT2B3/1/